# submit additional form data with jquery file upload and rails 3

Tags: jquery-plugins, ruby-on-rails-3.1, form-data

I have been trying to set up the tutorial, https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-Form-Data with rails 3. However I am slightly confused about how Form Data works with Rails Object. From my research it seems that Form Data with serializeData returns an array. However, I am totally lost about what to do after that.

I am wondering how do I use data.FormData and put it in my rails object. For example I have an art model in Rails that file upload will upload a picture to. What can i put in my controller under create so that the title of the art object correspond to the title under the label in td class="title" Title: input name="title[]" required /label /td "Thanks.

Regards,
Kane